# Why do good lifts feel effortless?

Tags: muscle, movements

I am curious what explains the difference between perceived effort and absolute effort for different types of movements. For example pull-ups and burpees always *feel hard*, while a 1RM snatch sometimes feels just effortless.

I know that there are concentric, isometric, eccentric movements. Is there a different neurological mechanism behind these that result in different perception, and if yes, how does that work?

Speed might be a factor as well. Are exertion of different muscle fiber types perceived differently?

What are the factors which determine the perceived effort of muscle movement, and how do they work?

Comment: Olympic style (explosive/plyo) stuff is different too in that it's super fast and you're only doing a couple of them. Drop the weight to 70% and do 20 of them; it will be a meat grinder. You're getting into lactic acid metabolite disruption as your body's way of safe guarding against overuse and mechanical failure.